# Categorize applications

Tags: android, categories

i would like to categorize applications.
When an app comes to foreground i should be able to detect that this app has video,audio,just text, or 3D graphics.

I tried using 2 options to categorize them:

1. to get the permissions used in the apps, but couldn't get permissions for 3rd party apps(only the native apps), is it true that you cannot get permissions for 3rd party apps? or am i missing something?
2. to pick out all installed apps based on mimeType, but i get only the native apps, or maybe certain apps(intents of apps) don't have the mimeType specified(am not sure).

is there any other way to categorize the installed applications? I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this?

thanks alot

Comment: Well for point 1) i could get permissions for some 3rd party apps as well, but how will i categorize it based on video or audio or others?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WhereDat](http://wheredatapp.com/developers/) API:

Create a **raw** [JSON POST](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) request, with an array of the packages you want to categorize:

```
{
  "packages": [
    "com.pixmix.mobileapp",
    "com.nextstagesearch"
  ]
}
```

Send it to:

http://api.wheredatapp.com/data

And here's the response:

```
{
"apps": [
    {
        "category": "Productivity",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "updated": 1436741473,
        "created": 1431028391,
        "icon_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/q5pFGfXKZejowwcmlJl7M1IXGHVM4Zq_IjPpYb7zgkUFXO3QnZ2LyeOUUhMPaKPkJ3gR=w300",
        "title": "WhereDat Beta",
        "package": "com.nextstagesearch",
        "ratings_count": 4,
        "short_description": "WhereDat lets you easily search your device for contacts, apps, and recently accessed webpages without leaving your home screen. With deep linking you can search the c..."
    },
    {
        "category": "Photography",
        "rating": 4.0519609451293945,
        "updated": 1435970764,
        "created": 1430868349,
        "icon_url": "https://lh3.ggpht.com/NgbwQzyo2mDR8su1Embio5jtHuPyScaMr0j4iub58YR5m19Ns0gVdeb9pYgNvMuFCcg=w300",
        "title": "PixMix - Photo sharing",
        "package": "com.pixmix.mobileapp",
        "ratings_count": 2040,
        "short_description": "Simple collage or photo sharing in just two clicks!★ See your photos in BEAUTIFUL albums★ Create beautiful album COLLAGE★ EASILY send albums to friends and family★ You..."
    }
]
}
```